# How to use groupby clause in Entity Framework and ASP.NET MVC and get count

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an chat model class as follows:

```
public class Chat
    {
        [Key]
        public int ChatId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string CustName { get; set; }


        public string Query { get; set; }

        public string Resolution { get; set; }

        public string Region { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public DateTime ChatStartDateTime { get; set; }

        public DateTime? ChatCreateDateTime { get; set; }

        public DateTime? ChatEndDateTime { get; set; }

        public string Feedback { get; set; }

        public DateTime? FeedbackDateTime { get; set; }

        public string FeedbackSharedBy { get; set; }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string DidCustCreateTicket { get; set; }

        [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Invalid Email Address")]
        public string CustEmail { get; set; }

        public int? ScenarioId { get; set; }
        public string ScenarioList { get; set; }


        [ForeignKey("Id")]
        public virtual User User { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ScenarioId")]
        public virtual Scenario Scenario { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Scenarios {get;set;}

        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Users { get; set; }

    }
```

I want to get the report of Chats such that how many Chats are added in Tool and group them with Scenarios and simply show Scenario Total Count.

For example:

[image: TOtal Chats Count groupby Scenario]

Here is the query that I have tried but could not know what I'm exactly doing :

```
public ActionResult test()
        {
            using (Db db = new Db())
            {
                ViewBag.resultset = db.Chats
            .Where(x => System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.ChatCreateDateTime) == DateTime.Today)
            .GroupBy(ddda => ddda.Scenario)
            .ToList()
            .Select(s => new
            {
                //month = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(s.Key),
                count = s.Count()
            });

                return View();
            }
        }
```

Help is much appreciated

Comment: Just select like this `.Select(s => new
            {
               Scenario = s.key,
                count = s.Count()
            });`

Answer (score 0):

Worked it out by creating another VM class as ScenarioVM with 2 propertied ScenarioName and Count, and use it in the query in action. Let  me know if any one needs help on this